# ionic App running on windows but does not run with ios emulator on mac

Tags: android, ios, xcode, macos, ionic-framework

I created an ionic app, it's working good. Even I uploaded it on google play. And than when I tried to create an ios version of my app; its running on XCode but it  can't pass splash screen and shows nothing other than splash screen.

Please help. I am new to mac and XCode.

Comment: Did you try to test the iOS version as a native app, by getting more informations about what is going on from the console ?

Comment: I tried to a blank ionic app. its working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

I changed 'AutoHideSplashScreen' value to true and my project is working now. At least I found the source of the problem, the splash screen wasn't hiding.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the `Android` version and not on the `iOS`, you should try to see if something goes wrong on the `console`. Did you try to run it on your device ?

I found this on Ionic official website :

> Once you have an account and you have set up XCode with your certificates to enable device testing, you’ll want to open the XCode project from platforms/ios/ and do your testing from XCode.